# Firebase web client error this.bgMessageHandler.next is not a function

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

Firebase client error `this.bgMessageHandler.next` is not a function.
All the steps are done as per: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

I have setup a firebase app with following setup:
A create react app, along with service worker file mentioned below.
Contents of my serviceworker file:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "lsdafjlksdfjlaskdfjlkadfjaldkf",
    authDomain: "abcd.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "abcd",
    storageBucket: "abcd.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "394504395830",
    appId: "asdljfdkjflasdf"
  });

const messaging = firebase.messaging(firebaseApp);
  
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
    console.log('sw [firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    const notificationOptions = {
      body: 'Background Message body.',
      icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };
  
    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
  });
```

I am firing the notification from the backend via Firebase compose notification UI from firebase console.

Answer (score 4):

This was happening because I was using mixed instructions from:https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

It has two versions of code: namespaced and modular. consistently use any one of them.

The idea is to consistently use a single kind,
For e.g. my serviceworker script uses namespaced kind, evident from `importScripts`. So in the backgroundMessage listener registration,
the correct version is to use a single argument which is callback.

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```